# .Net 4.7 - Azure WebJob Project - JobHostConfiguration/RunAndBlock missing after NuGet updates

Tags: azure-webjobs, .net-4.7.2

I had a working project with very dated NuGet package set for WebJob and storage. After a massive upgrade, I'm having three errors in this block only:

```
    private static void Main()
    {
        var config = new JobHostConfiguration();

        config.Queues.MaxDequeueCount    = Convert.ToInt32(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MaxDequeueCount"]);
        config.Queues.MaxPollingInterval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(Convert.ToInt32(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MaxPollingInterval"]));
        config.Queues.BatchSize          = Convert.ToInt32(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["BatchSize"]); ;
        config.NameResolver              = new QueueNameResolver();

        if (config.IsDevelopment)
        {
            config.UseDevelopmentSettings();
        }

        var host = new JobHost();
        host.RunAndBlock();
    }
```

Errors:

```
Error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'JobHostConfiguration' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) \Program.cs:11
Error CS7036: There is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal parameter 'options' of 'JobHost.JobHost(IOptions<JobHostOptions>, IJobHostContextFactory)' \Program.cs:23
Error CS1061: 'JobHost' does not contain a definition for 'RunAndBlock' and no accessible extension method 'RunAndBlock' accepting a first argument of type 'JobHost' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) \Program.cs:24
```

All the helps and questions are showing .Net Core code. I'm on .Net Framework 4.7.2. How do I go about setting up this code in old framework?

Comment: Could you please the version of package `Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs` you use?

Comment: @JimXu I upgraded to v3.0.22

Comment: Do you have any other concerns? if you have no other concerns, could you please accept it as  an answer?

Comment: @JimXu Sorted out. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to Azure WebJob SDK V3, the `JobHostConfiguration` and `JobHost` have been removed. In version V3, the host is an implementation of `IHost`. For more details, please refer to [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk/issues/1870#issuecomment-417888043) and [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/webjobs-sdk-how-to#webjobs-sdk-versions). Besides, please note that in version 3, you need to explicitly install the Storage binding extension required by the WebJobs SDK.

For example (Queue trigger in version 3)

```
#Install package Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Storage 3.x
static async Task Main()
{
    var builder = new HostBuilder();
    builder.ConfigureWebJobs(b =>
    {
        b.AddAzureStorageCoreServices();
        b.AddAzureStorage(a => {
            a.BatchSize = 8;
            a.NewBatchThreshold = 4;
            a.MaxDequeueCount = 4;
            a.MaxPollingInterval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(15);
        });
    });
    var host = builder.Build();
    using (host)
    {
        await host.RunAsync();
    }
}
```